Dynamic Form in Oracle APEX
I currently have an APEX requirement that tracks the progress of assessments of various items.  These assessments contain a few hundred questions that change regularly.  I want to create a form as one of the ways to answer these questions but I need the form to dynamically change the amount of questions, and the wording of the questions.
These questions are stored as rows in a table.  I am under the impression that the form region associates each entry with a column from its source query, and due to the sheer amount of questions, I reach the character limit by listing them all in a pivot.
My solution currently was to have the form pulled from a collection and have each of the page items attached to the form have a server-side condition that hides them so it appears to be changing.
This solution works, but you are limited to the 50 columns in a collection and I need the amount of entries to be higher.  If anyone is aware of a better way of accomplishing this requirement I would be very appreciative of some guidance.

Without thinking too deep about the direction you took - presuming you like the outcome collections provide - you can build your own. Premise behind collections is that it stores the APEX session_id against each record. In other cases some people build their own table for circumstances where volume is high and they want specific indexing.
